# Why doesn't PHP XPath find table elements even though Firefox shows they exist?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I am trying to pull an exact table during a "web scrape."
Used cURL to pull page into $html, which succeeds fine.

Used Firebug to get exact XPATH to the table needed.

Code follows:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument($html);
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$summary = $xpath->evaluate('/html/body/table[5]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td/table');
echo "Summary Length: " . $summary->length;
```

When executed, $summary->length is always zero.  It doesn't pull that table node.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my XPath query (scraping HTML tables) only work in Firebug, but not the application I'm developing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241029/why-does-my-xpath-query-scraping-html-tables-only-work-in-firebug-but-not-the)

Answer (score 4):

Firefox is liable to insert "virtual" `tbody` elements into tables that don't have them; do those elements exist in the original file?

Comment: No, they don't.  But I do see them in firefox.

I have used XPath Checker as well and can see the data I need.  But using it in my PHP xpath->evaluate never returns data.

Comment: <tr> is not allowed inside <table> directly - there has to be a <tbody> / <thead> / <tfoot>.  It's implied if not specified directly.  HTML is weird like that... the start and end tags can both be optional!

Comment: If the the tbody elements don't exist in the original file, then they shouldn't be in your PHP xpath query.

Comment: I apologize.  The TBODY tags are there.  I overlooked them when first looking at the source.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove "/tbody". From xpath you got from firefox:

> .//*[@id='data']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span

create this:

> .//*[@id='data']/tr[1]/td[2]/span

Aloe